# Reducer not importing the action type constants

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a root reducer which imports action type constants from the another file. When the reducer is called for the first time because of the createstore, the values of these constants are undefined.

I tried converting those constants into functions and it gave me error- "Object can not be function". When I printed its type, it initially gave me undefined but later calls prints the type- function.

My directory structure is such

```
helpers/
 -index.js
 -store.js
 -constants.js

reducers/
 -index.js
 -rootReducer.js
```

Every index.js file is of type-

```
export * from './rootReducer'
```

This is my store file (store.js)-

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { rootReducer } from '../reducers'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

const initialState = {}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
)
```

This is my constants file (constants.js)-

```
export const constants = {
    BENCHMARK_DATA_RECEIVED: 'BENCHMARK_DATA_RECEIVED',
    BENCHMARK_DATA_FAILED: 'BENCHMARK_DATA_FAILED',
}
```

This is my root reducer (rootReducer.js)-

```
import { constants } from '../helpers'

export const rootReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log(constants)
    // Initially print undefined
    // After that prints correct value

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BENCHMARK_DATA_RECEIVED':
            return { ...state, benchmark_data: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am no sure about what is causing this problem but it only happens when the reducer is used first time ( most probably while creating store ). I have googled a lot but has not come across any such questions. Maybe there is some problem with my setup. Also printing those constants anywhere (like in action creators) works fine.

Comment: Why are you importing constants from `'../helpers'` if they're defined in `constants.js`?

Comment: My index.js file in helpers folder exports all things from each file- ```export * from './store'
export * from './constants'
```

Comment: Also your initial state is an array but then you're changing it into object.

Comment: Sorry, it is an object ```const initialState = {}```

Comment: Does it have the same error if you import constants directly from `constants.js` in your reducer?

Comment: I just checked it. No, it does not have that problem when I import it directly. Why is that so?

Comment: Looks like it's not bundled properly or your file structure is wrong, you'd check for warnings in terminal when you start your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used madge (https://github.com/pahen/madge) to create the dependency graph and I found out that I had got circular dependency. Here is the link for the image- https://imgur.com/Qf3wmQ2 . You may want to put an answer there so that I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the comments, you can import directly from `constants.js` in your reducer and meanwhile investigate the file structure you have.